# Make IE8 as default browser when IE9 browser installed

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I need to run my mvc application automatcally in IE browser. so i kept IE as default browser.but what my requirement is i need to run my application automatically in IE8 browser instead of higher version like IE9.

my system having IE9 browser installed. when i execute the application it runs through IE9 browser so every time i am going to change the browser mode by using developer tools (F12) available in IE.

how can i avoid this situation and make IE8 as default browser when IE9 is installed.

**Note:** don't expect answer like uninstall IE9 browser and install IE8 for my requirement.because  for other application requires IE9 browser.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Too bad you aren't using ie 11  seriously though you can't run in the older versions. You can make ie 9 use the outdated engine with the following meta tag.

```
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
```